# Cities and Players, what to prepare?

Tags: dnd-5e, world-building

So this is going to be a very open-ended question about city design(/description) and what players tend to ask about their surroundings. In my experience, players tend to be extremely curious about the most random things and jump past plothooks often enough. I am fine giving them that agency, and would like it if they could enjoy the directions in which they explore their surrounds in the same session. (instead of me trying to make an impromptu setting before fleshing it before the next session)

What are some of the more common questions that players tend to ask about **Cities**?

I have a whole notebook for random character life-stories that I can reference when players hang onto an NPC who was initially not important, but I have nothing similar for cities.

As a player what are the common questions that you would ask about a city you just entered ? Or more generally how can I properly flesh out any random city ?

*I understand that different people will have different questions and I am fine with that as I would like to make a general guideline that I can follow when I design cities in future sessions.